# Proving that the set $([0,1[, \ast)$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let in the set $G=[0,1[$ the operation $\ast$ defined by $a\ast b=a+b-[a+b]$ with $[a+b]$  the integer part of $a+b$, i.e,  $a\ast b$ is the decimal part of $a+b$.

I need proof that $(G, \ast)$ is a group and I tried all the group axioms except the associativity of the operation.

Can you help please.

Comment: This group operation can be written as $(a+b) \bmod 1$, which may make it simpler to handle. In this context, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De facto addition mod 1, $ a*b*c=(a+b+c)-[a+b+c] $

associativity: $ (a*b)*c = (a+b -[a+b]) +c - [a+b -[a+b] +c] = (a+b+c) - [a+b] - [a+b+c] + [a+b] = (a+b+c) - [a+b+c] $,  using $ [[a+b]]=[a+b] $

$ a*(b*c) $ idem

Comment: Slepecky why $(a+b -[a+b]) +c - [a+b -[a+b] +c] = (a+b+c) - [a+b] - [a+b+c] + [a+b]$?

Comment: Also explain the 1st line...

Comment: for 0<= a,b,c<1
[a+b+c - [a+b]] = 

:a) = [a+b+c] = [a+b+c] - [a+b] if a+b<1
:b) = [a+b+c-1] = [a+b+c]-1 if 1<=a+b<2

Comment: $[a+b+c -[a+b]]= a+b+c -[a+b]$ for the property $[x\pm m]=[x]\pm m$ if $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: yes But only m=0 or m=1 is possible for m=[a+b]